# Left Join returning duplicate rows sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Orderline and InvoiceLine. I need to display the data in a single line based on the orderid and the orderitemkey

Table: Orderline

```
+---------+--------------+--------+
| OrderId | OrderItemKey | Amount |
+---------+--------------+--------+
|     410 |           10 |     25 |
|     410 |           20 |     50 |
+---------+--------------+--------+
```

Table: InvoiceLine

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
| Invoiceid | Description | InvoiceAmt | OrderId | OrderItemKey |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
|         1 | xxxx        |         10 |      10 |         410 |
|         2 | bbb         |         15 |      10 |         410 |
|         3 | ccccc       |         50 |      20 |         410 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+
```

```
WITH ORDERLINE AS
SELECT orderid, 
    orderitemkey, 
    amount 
    FROM   tbl_orderline ), invoiceline AS 
    ( 
     SELECT   invoiceid, 
              max(description), 
              sum(invoiceamt), 
              orderid, 
              orderitemkey 
     FROM     tbl_invoiceline 
     GROUP BY invoiceid, 
              orderid, 
              orderitemkey )SELECT    O.ORDERID, 
      O.ORDERITEMKEY, 
      O.AMOUNT, 
      I.invoiceid, 
      I.description, 
      I.invoiceamt 
FROM TBL_ORDERLINE O 
LEFT JOIN TBL_INVOICELINE 
ON  O.ORDERID = I.orderid 
AND O.ORDERITEMKEY = I.orderitemkey
```

The data should be displayed as follows:

```
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemKey | Amount | InvoiceID | Description | InvoiceAmt |
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|     410 |           10 |     25 |         1 | xxxx        |         10 |
|         |              |        |         2 | bbb         |         15 |
|     410 |           20 |     50 |         3 | ccccc       |         50 |
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

But it is displaying as below:

```
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemKey | Amount | InvoiceID | Description | InvoiceAmt |
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|     410 |           10 |     25 |         1 | xxxx        |         10 |
|     410 |          140 |     25 |         2 | bbb         |         15 |
|     410 |           20 |     50 |         3 | ccccc       |         50 |
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Any help, please?

I am using MS SQL.
For the orderitemkey it's a mistake, it is displaying 10.

```
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| OrderId | OrderItemKey | Amount | InvoiceID | Description | InvoiceAmt |
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|      10 |          410 |     25 |         1 | xxxx        |         10 |
|      10 |          410 |     25 |         2 | bbb         |         15 |
|      20 |          410 |     50 |         3 | ccccc       |         50 |
+---------+--------------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle (plsql)?

Comment: In your actual results, you are showing an OrderItemKey of 140. Is this what you get, or is it a mistake?

Comment: The result set doesn't have duplicate rows. Some of the fields in some of the rows are the same, but none of the rows are identical. So, the query is working as it should.

Comment: Your CTE name is not same in your select statement and In your sample data orderId value is not same how can you join them

Comment: OrderItemKey in invoiceLine is OrderID in Orderline?

Comment: Do you really want a SELECT to return the blank lines as if it was a pivot table in excel? In Excel pivot tables theres a feature to repeat grouping rows or not.

Comment: i have suggestion one solution is merge cell in code side.

Comment: @jarlh I am using ms sql

Comment: @KimSullivan Normally I use ssrs to display the data, it is repeating the the row which I don't want

Comment: @bvmcode There was a mistake in the attachment I corrected it

Comment: @GenishParvadia could you please advise how to do the merging?

Comment: @user3168314 which control use display data (ex. gridview)?

Comment: @GenishParvadia It's a tablix

Comment: This is a basic type of parent/child report. It has been asked and answered hundreds if not thousands of times all over SO and everywhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data looks to be returned OK (you have 3 lines in InvoiceLine and you get 3 lines in your output).

If you just want to do a pretty formatting using SSRS, you need to [use tablix groupings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017).

If you really need to return the data from the SQL in the format you want, you need to re-think the join - because you only want the grouped `ORDERLINE` to be joined to the first row of `INVOICELINE`, you need to actually [number the rows in invoiceline using window functions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-window-functions-in-sql-server/) - something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY invoiceid, orderid, orderitemkey PARTITIONBY orderid, orderitemkey) AS RowNumber` and then join `ON (... RowNumber = 1)`.

Comment: I have been able to solve the issue. I used ROWNUMBER and filter when ROWNUMBER is equal 1. Thank everyone :)